# how do i filter an itertools chain() result?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-itertools

in my views,
if i import an itertools module:

```
from itertools import chain
```

and i chain some objects with it:

```
franktags = Frank.objects.order_by('date_added').reverse().filter(topic__exact='art') 
amytags = Amy.objects.order_by('date_added').reverse().filter(topic__exact='art') 
timtags = Tim.objects.order_by('date_added').reverse().filter(topic__exact='art') 
erictags = Eric.objects.order_by('date_added').reverse().filter(topic__exact='art')

ourtags = list(chain(franktags, amytags, timtags, erictags))
```

how do i then order "ourtags" by the "date_added"?

not surpisingly,

```
ourtags = list(chain(franktags, amytags, timtags, erictags)).order_by('date_added')
```

returns an "'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'" error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import operator

ourtags = sorted(ourtags, key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'))
```

Comment: i thought the answer would be straightforward. thank goodness i was right. thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Is using attrgetter different than using a lambda function?

Answer (score 5):

By this point in the code, you've already loaded up all of the objects into memory and into a list.  Just sort the list like you would any old Python list.

```
>>> import operator
>>> ourtags.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'))
```